Powerapp Canvas app - How to get email addresses of a Sharepoint List Person column?
I have a Sharepoint list that has the columns:

Step (integer starts from 1)

Document (lookup column from a Sharepoint Library)

Type of Task (a Choice column containing Draft, Review)

Users (Person/Group Column that Allow Multiple Selections).
Example of the list:
 Step   Document   Type of Task   Users
 1      Doc1       Draft          Smith,John Smith, Mary
 2      Doc1       Review         Smith, Anne



In my Powerapp canvas app, how can I get the emails of Document Doc1, Step 1 ie. emails of Smith,John and Smith, Mary, so that I can send an email to this list of people ?
Thank you

SharePoint Person columns are represented in Power Apps as a record with many fields, one of them being "Email" which containes the information you want. So if you are showing the list in a gallery, for example, you can get the e-mail addresses by using an expression such as the one below, which will return the e-mails separated by ;
Concat(ThisItem.Users, ThisRecord.Email, ";")

For example, if you want to send e-mail to those users inside a gallery, you would use something like
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
  Concat(ThisItem.Users, ThisRecord.Email, ";"),
  "test subject",
  "test body")

Or if you want to find the e-mails for a specific record, once you fetch the record you can use a similar expression:
With(
  { record: LookUp(YourSPList, Step = 1 And Document = "Doc1") },
  Concat(record.Users, ThisRecord.Email, ";")
)

Similar to the previous one, if you want to send an e-mail to those users, the app would have an expression similar to this one:
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
  With(
    { record: LookUp(YourSPList, Step = 1 And Document = "Doc1") },
    Concat(record.Users, ThisRecord.Email, ";")
  ),
  "test subject",
  "test body")


Thank you so much for your answer. I will try that. If I need to do the same thing from a PowerAutomate, how can I do that ? Thank you

How do you use record in this command ? Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(record,"test subject","test body")

Added a few more examples using the e-mails in an Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2 action

That works. Thank you so much !
